# Aplicar getTime a posicion de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente array:

```
[{"data":[["2020-06-04T14:30:50.00Z",2.82],
          ["2020-06-04T14:24:40.00Z",2.83]],
  "name":["CE del medio","Hortisys"]},
 {"data":[["2020-06-04T14:30:50.00Z",25.5],
         ["2020-06-04T14:24:40.00Z",26]],
  "name":["Temp. Ambiente","Hortisys"]}]
```

Necesito acceder a la primera posición del array data donde esta la fecha y aplicarle `new Date(fecha).getTime()`

Ejemplo  new Date(2020-06-04T14:30:50.00Z).getTime().

Estoy realizando esto con dos forEach y me gustaria saber como puedo actualizar los datos del array

multi es el array

```
this.multi.forEach(element => {

          element.data.forEach(element2 => {
            console.log('element', new Date(element2[0]).getTime());

          });

          

        });
```

Edit con la solución con dos for:

```
this.multi.forEach(element => {

          element.data.forEach(element2 => {
            element2[0] = new Date(element2[0]).getTime();
            // return new Date(element2[0]).getTime();

          });

          

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Como estas trabajando con array anidados, necesitas acceder a la posición `[0][0]` para obtener la fecha que quieres

```
const out = multi.map(x => {
   console.log(`Salida ${new Date(x.data[0][0]).getTime()}`);
});
```

```js
const multi = [
{
  data: [
    ["2020-06-04T14:30:50.00Z", 2.82],
    ["2020-06-04T14:24:40.00Z", 2.83]
  ],
  name: ["CE del medio", "Hortisys"]
},
{
  data: [
    ["2020-06-04T14:30:50.00Z", 25.5],
    ["2020-06-04T14:24:40.00Z", 26]
  ],
  name: ["Temp. Ambiente", "Hortisys"]
}
];

const out = multi.map(x => {
   console.log(`Salida ${new Date(x.data[0][0]).getTime()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

De esta forma puedes obtener lo que necesitas, siempre y cuando el elemento este en la primera posición, ten en cuenta eso ;)

Nos comentas si te sirve

Comment: Hola Paulo, gracias por la ayuda pero no es solo la posición [0][0] tendría que ser [i][0] ya que con todas las de dentro de data. lo he conseguido anidando dos for, pero no se como guardar el resultado x ese valor cambiado respetando todo lo demas

Comment: Hola de nuevo, hoy estoy muy espeso muchas horas de trabajo, simplemente era igualarlo            element2[0] = new Date(element2[0]).getTime(); Aun asi me vendria bien la ayudar para hacerlo con .map y no con for gracias

Comment: Map cumple la función de loop, por eso puedes usarlo perfectamente para recorrer arreglos. Si pruebas el código que te pase, te darás cuenta que funciona perfecto para lo que necesitas 